# Extjs - Sending extraparameters using model.save method

Tags: ajax, extjs, model, extjs4

I was wondering if there is any way to pass an array of objects as extra param of model.save method ?
For simple types params seem to work.

```
Ext.define('RightGridModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',  type: 'int'},
        {name: 'rightText',   type: 'string'},
        {name: 'digit',type:'int'}
    ]
});
 var mod = Ext.create('RightGridModel');
                            mod.set('rightText', 'some text');
mod.save({
                                url: "Home/Insert",
                                params: {
                                    par: 'additional parameter'
                                }
                            });
```

However if I want to send and array as an extra param,(of course I changed server side function to be approperiate ) par variable is an empty list. Here is a code I use to send an model and array

```
 mod.save({
                                url: "Home/Insert",
                                params: {
                                    par: Ext.encode(array)
                                }
                            });
```

Is there any way to send a model and an array as extra parameter ?? What is the best way to achieve that ?

Comment: Why do you not want to add the extra parameter into the model?

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible through the save method. You'll have to create your own if you want to add new parameters in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `getParams` function of Proxy class. You can just subclass existing proxy classes into your own and use it while communicating with your backend.